# How to parse file in php and generate insert statements for mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

In case of csv file we have `fgetcsv` in php to parse and get the output but in my case file is `.dat` and I need to parse it and store it into MySQL Database and so do we have any built in function in php like `fgetcsv` that can work in similar fashion on `.dat` file ?

Here is the sample value, it has headers DF_PARTY_ID;DF_PARTY_CODE;DF_CONNECTION_ID and its value as mentioned under.

Sample Data:

```
DF_PARTY_ID;DF_PARTY_CODE;DF_CONNECTION_ID

87961526;4002524;13575326
87966204;4007202;13564782
```

Comment: What's in the .dat file? .dat isn't a standard format and doesn't give us any hint as to how the data is structured.

Comment: Have updated question with some sample data in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with `fgetcsv()`? The extension on the file is irrelevant as long as the format of the data is consistent across all of your files.

**Example**:

```
$fh = fopen('example.dat', 'r');
while (!feof($fh)) {
        var_dump(fgetcsv($fh, 0, ';'));
}
```

Alternatively, with PHP5.3 you can also do:

```
$lines = file('example.dat');
foreach($lines as $line) {
        var_dump(str_getcsv(trim($line), 0, ';'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO `.dat` files can be of different formats. Blindly following the extension can be error-prone. If however you have a file from some specific application, maybe tell us what this app is. Chances are there are some parsing libraries or routines.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine it would be easier to write a short function using `fopen`, `fread`, and `fclose` to parse it yourself. Read each line, explode to an array, and store them as you wish.